# Meet with CrashLoopBackOff and ContainerCreating status when apply contiv-vpp cni to k8s master node

Tags: kubernetes

I'm using kubertenes version v1.21.2 to simply deploy a master node and a worker node respectly on KVM virtual machine(ubuntu 20.04 LTS).But after I run `kubectl apply -f`  to apply contiv-vpp cni, some pods get status of CrashLoopBackOff and ContainerCreating.
The two node are `Ready`

```
NAME     STATUS   ROLES                  AGE   VERSION
master   Ready    control-plane,master   20h   v1.21.2
node     Ready    <none>                 17h   v1.21.2
```

I have run `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` and the info as following:

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                             READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   contiv-crd-rlmjd                 1/1     Running             2          18h
kube-system   contiv-etcd-0                    1/1     Running             2          18h
kube-system   contiv-ksr-598zr                 1/1     Running             2          18h
kube-system   contiv-vswitch-5pfjp             1/1     Running             0          17h
kube-system   contiv-vswitch-hnbzx             0/1     CrashLoopBackOff    217        18h
kube-system   coredns-558bd4d5db-46bvr         0/1     ContainerCreating   0          20h
kube-system   coredns-558bd4d5db-t957f         0/1     ContainerCreating   0          20h
kube-system   etcd-master                      1/1     Running             3          20h
kube-system   kube-apiserver-master            1/1     Running             3          20h
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-master   1/1     Running             3          20h
kube-system   kube-proxy-5v4vj                 1/1     Running             0          17h
kube-system   kube-proxy-7jkt6                 1/1     Running             3          20h
kube-system   kube-scheduler-master            1/1     Running             3          20h
```

By `kubectl describe pod coredns-558bd4d5db-46bvr -n kube-system`, I find that the coredns pod keep `ContainerCreating` state due to message below:

```
 Type     Reason                  Age                     From     Message
  ----     ------                  ----                    ----     -------
  Normal   SandboxChanged          8m31s (x957 over 88m)   kubelet  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  3m29s (x1005 over 87m)  kubelet  (combined from similar events): Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container "2a715c3aa43740540c1eae78d56f2eae6c75fc3bfe8c8f796c00867e4346a409" network for pod "coredns-558bd4d5db-46bvr": networkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "coredns-558bd4d5db-46bvr_kube-system" network: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial unix /var/run/contiv/cni.sock: connect: no such file or directory"
```

so is the another coredns pod.

I think is quite clear that the question is lacking `cni.sock` file, but I donot know how to create or get it back.
In the `contiv-vpp.yaml`(which have been applied by `kubectl apply -f`) I find a line that maybe result in this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oYfS.png)

Remove this line and re-apply got the same status and message, still lack `cni.sock`.
Please help me bros, I have google it for days and just can't fix it by myself.

Comment: I've also faced the similar problem in Kind cluster. Reinstalling Kind worked for me.

Comment: can you try giving some more output via "kubectl get events". this should tell you more about why the containers are crashing

Comment: How did you install Kubernetes ?
Did you use the [Contiv-VPP documentation](https://github.com/contiv/vpp#quickstart) during the installation ?

Comment: @meaningqo  On the contrary, got ```No resources found in default namespace.```

Comment: @matt_j I can confirm that follow the documentation during installation, and use the lastest version.

Comment: Sorry mates, I really didn't expect to get any futher replies, so forget to check my question. I'm now trying to reinstall it with lower version like ```ubuntu18.04```, hope for a success.